# Convection and radiation heat transfer

Tags: thermodynamics

It's been some years since my last physics exam and I really need a refreshment in this. I'm stuck in getting a rough estimation of heat exchange between 2 objects separeted by air: let's say object 1 is 900 K and object 2 is at room temperature (300 K), so exchange will take place by convection and radiation due to the high temperature of object 1.

Knowing the objects surfaces, their thermal properties and the medium between them, is there a way to get an idea of the temperature rise of object 2 without using a finite element software?

A little bit more difficult example: what if between object 1 and 2 i have air and a third object, for example a glass surface which is transparent to heat radiation. How can i get an estimation of temperature rising of object 2? Can i go for a "hand calculation" or is the complexity too high?

Comment: Have you tried using u values/ r values?

Comment: You are confused with the heat transfer in your situation. Unless your objects are emitting light http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_transfer#Radiation , your two sticks would only exchange heat by means of convection.

Comment: @Keith: Wouldn't an object at 900K emit a considerable amount of Infra-red light? Isn't iron red-hot at about 800K?

Comment: @danimal: not yet, will have a look tonight when i'll be back from work..gotta bring back some university books i think :)

Comment: @Keith: why isn't radiation involved? Every object at any temperature above 0 K is emitting radiation, and light becomes visible only over 800 K..is the radiation part negligible before that temperature, compared to convection?

Comment: From experience with UHV experiments and sample annealing, at $800\;\mathrm{K}$ I expect a notable loss due to radiation. So the hot object will heat the cold one via radiation as well. I would consider convection (hot air going up) a bad mechanism for transfer if the objects are next to each other. It will cool the hot object, of course.

Comment: Hi @user3211966. You will need to know the size of your objects. This will determine the total radiative heat emitted by each object. You can then carry out a radiative heat transfer calculation based upon their view factors. This will output the radiative heat flux arriving at your exposed object. You will then need to know the thermophysical properties of your receiver. You can carry out a steady state heat transfer analysis to estimate the increase in temperature of your receiver.